# Tortoise overlay DLL registration failed

Tags: tortoisesvn, dllregistration

I am working on a windows app that has the functionality to set overlay icon for folder and ANY TYPE of files. I am using the SVN tortoise overlayicon dll to achieve this functionality. But now when I try to register the tortoiseoverlay.dll file, it gives below error:

The module "D:\bin\Release64\bin\TortoiseOverlays.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "D:\bin\Release64\bin\TortoiseOverlays.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

can anyone provide some light over it and point out what I am suppose to do to get this bug fix.

For clerification: I am using windows7 (64bit)
Visual Studio 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dll does not provide its own registering function. And that's by design: as the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/TortoiseOverlays/version-1.1.3/Documentation.txt) clearly state:

> How to install/redistribute TortoiseOverlays:
>   --------------------------------------------- You can either install TortoiseOverlays with the provided merge module (which is the
>   recommended way, because it can properly handle the  required
>   reference counting of the registry keys and dlls), or use the also
>   provided msi installer. You **MUST NOT** try to install the dll and
>   create the registry keys yourself! If you have a non-msi installer,
>   you can call the msi installer like this: msiexec /i
>   TortoiseOverlays-1.0.0.XXXX-win32.msi /qn /norestart